# To assign a random icon to each label VC++

Tags: c#, visual-c++, c++-cli

Following is a part of code taken from 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd553230.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1

---

```
/// Assign each icon from the list of icons to a random square

// The TableLayoutPanel has 16 labels and the icon list has 16 icons,so an icon is pulled at random from the listand added to each label


private void AssignIconsToSquares()
{

    foreach (Control control in tableLayoutPanel1.Controls)
    {
        Label iconLabel = control as Label;
        if (iconLabel != null)
        {
            int randomNumber = random.Next(icons.Count);
            iconLabel.Text = icons[randomNumber];
            // iconLabel.ForeColor = iconLabel.BackColor;
            icons.RemoveAt(randomNumber);
        }
    }
}
```

I want to write the same code in VC++ instead. I have tried but not succeeded yet. Is there any way to use 'keyword as' in VC++? Is it possible to write the same code in VC++ syntax. My version of code is as follows,

```
private: void AssignIconsToSquares()
{
    for each (Label^ label in tableLayoutPanel1)
    {
        if (label != "0")
        {
            Random^ random = gcnew Random();
            int randomNumber = random->Next(0, 17);
            label->Text = icons[randomNumber];
        }
    }
}
```

I recieved many error like

> error C3285: for each statement cannot operate on variables of type 'System::Windows::Forms::TableLayoutPanel ^' left of '->Text' must point to class/struct/union/generic type

Would appericiate if someone help me to sort it out.

Regards

Comment: It's `managed C++` you mean I think rather than "VC++ syntax"

Comment: Or rather `C++/CLI`... `managed C++` is the older deprecated version.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The error means that the `Text` member does not appear to belong to the item you are using (`label`).

You seem to be missing a bit of the port:

```
foreach (Control control in tableLayoutPanel1.Controls)
{
```

I guess that in your managed C++ example it should be something like:

```
private: void AssignIconsToSquares()
{
    for each (Control^ control in tableLayoutPanel1.Controls)
    {
        Label^ thislabel = safe_cast<Label^>(control);
        if (thislabel != NULL)
        {
            Random^ random = gcnew Random();
            int randomNumber = random->Next(0, 17);
            thislabel->Text = icons[randomNumber];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Toppen Dennis! I figured it out how to convert Control to Label and my code is working, here is line i added to.                                                      Label^ thislabel = safe_cast<Label^>(control);

Comment: @SalarAskar Good. If my answer helped then please accept it. :)

Comment: @Downvoter - Please be helpful and add a comment to say what your problem with my answer is. That way I will be able to improve it and improve SO.